# A pending status after command "kubectl create -f busybox.yaml"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a picture below of my mac.

- K8S Cluster(on VirtualBox, 1*master, 2*workers)
- OS Ubuntu 15.04
- K8S version 1.1.1

When I try to create a pod "busybox.yaml" it goes to pending status.
How can I resolve it?

I pasted the online status below for understanding with a picture (kubectl describe node).

- Status
  kubectl get nodes
  192.168.56.11   kubernetes.io/hostname=192.168.56.11   Ready      7d
  192.168.56.12   kubernetes.io/hostname=192.168.56.12   Ready      7d
- kubectl get ev
  1h  39s  217  busybox Pod  FailedScheduling {scheduler } no nodes available to schedule pods
- kubectl get pods
  NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  busybox   0/1       Pending   0          1h

And I also added one more status.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

"kubectl describe pod busybox" or "kubectl get pod busybox -o yaml" output could be useful.

Since you didn't specify, I assume that the busybox pod was created in the default namespace, and that no resource requirements nor nodeSelectors were specified.

In many cluster setups, including vagrant, we create a LimitRange for the default namespace to request a nominal amount of CPU for each pod (.1 cores). You should be able to confirm that this is the case using "kubectl get pod busybox -o yaml".

We also create a number of system pods automatically. You should be able to see them using "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide".

It is possible for nodes with sufficiently small capacity to fill up with just system pods, though I wouldn't expect this to happen with 2-core nodes.

If the busybox pod were created before the nodes were registered, that could be another reason for that event, though I would expect to see a subsequent event for the reason that the pod remained pending even after nodes were created.

Please take a look at the troubleshooting guide for more troubleshooting tips, and follow up here on on slack (slack.k8s.io) with more information.

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/troubleshooting.html

Comment: i did "kubectl describe ~~" to see more details like you mentioned. the pod was spawned well by scheduler to one of worker nodes somewhere. but, it showed me pending...when i restart kubelet again..then the pending status changed to running. and also to let you know..why sometimes worker nodes turned into notready state? whenever i met the state ..i have to restart it to make it run.